# iOS Instruments: Memory/CPU activity with associated threads

Tags: iphone, ios, performance-testing, xcode-instruments

Instruments provides tools to see threads, activity of I/O, DB, network etc. But I have come across a situation where I need to see the influence of a thread i.e. CPU/Memory use that its causing.

1. I think threads are self explanatory(Identification, what does it do)
2. But, How to correlate things on thread-wise basis?

Thanks,
Venkatarao

Comment: If your code is running in the Simulator, you can easily use DTrace (the OS technology Instruments runs on top of) to track per-thread function calls of any type, including memory allocations and frees, system calls, database library calls, network accesses, etc. Unfortunately, DTrace is not available on the iOS devices themselves last I checked.